# Invoke OSGeo4W commands with Java

Tags: gdal, java, osgeo, osgeo4w

I want to use the command gdal_polygonize image.png bla in a Java for-loop, where image.png and bla changes in every iteration. How can I do this?

I searched for it on google and stackexchange and I only found a similiar question for Python (but it is not quite answered I think).

Any suggestions? Maybe a Batch script which I could run in every iteration?

Comment: As [answered previously](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26663787/327026), use the Java API.

Comment: Thanks but it took me a long time to get it work with osgeo4w and now I want to keep it :D Anyway I found another way. (see answer below). Again thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html) 
It is very simple. Example: for `gdal_polygonize hello.png bla` 
you can use:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
    import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
    import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;
    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecuteException, IOException {

             String line = "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\OSGeo4W.bat";
             CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
             commandLine.addArgument("gdal_polygonize");
             commandLine.addArgument("hello.png"); //Use path to image if necessary
             commandLine.addArgument("bla"); //Use path if necessary 
             DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
             executor.execute(commandLine);

         }
   }
```